# How get friends engagement using facebook graph api?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Nowadays Facebook lists engagements in the events like birthdays and I want to show engagements to my website.

Is there any way to get friends engagement through the graph API?

Answer (score 0):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/events
```

get array using it and check using if condition if it is engagements date show to your site Or Save to database 
if you save all date 1st in database then check for
if current date is engagements date then show it to database